# Can't read data from External JSON file to my HTML page

Tags: javascript, json

I want to read data from this JSON file:
[Link](https://wcsecure.weblink.com.au/Clients/aquabotix/weblink.aspx)

This is my code:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Javascript:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X355mznvFw/

Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0 at
>   JSON.parse

Comment: Please put your code here, in your question.  Do not put it on an external site and link to it.  Please post only the relevant code and not a dump of your entire program.

Comment: That file isn't JSON, it is JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

That file isn't JSON, it is JSONP.  You would consume it by doing the following:

1. Create a global function that the JSONP document will call and provide with data.
2. Add the document as a script so that it loads and is interpreted as JavaScript.
3. Do whatever you want with the data **in the callback**.  The data will not be global.

```js
// Create a callback function for the JSONP response to call
function WL_HeadlineCallBack(data){
  console.log(data)
}

// Create a script to load the JSONP document
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "THE URL OF THE JSONP DOCUMENT";
document.head.appendChild(script);

// The body of the JSONP document rougly matches:
/*
WL_HeadlineCallBack(
{
    "WebLinkHeadlineData":{
       ...
    }
}
)
*/
```